# Sidekiq push_bulk to batch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm trying to use Sidekiq batches to group a set of related jobs together. However, the batch prematurely fires on complete callback's since the `jobs` method can't push all the jobs to Redis fast enough. The sidekiq documentation at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches says this can be resolved by using the `Sidekiq::Client.push_bulk` method but the documentation is unclear on how to push to a batch in bulk. Can someone share an example of how to use `push_bulk` in the context of a batch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume you want to process 100 users in a batch, one user ID per job.

```
b = Sidekiq::Batch.new
b.jobs do
  users = User.select(:id).limit(100).map(&:id) # users is [1, 2, 3, etc...]
  args = users.map {|uid| [uid] } # args is [[1], [2], [3], etc...]
  Sidekiq::Client.push_bulk('class' => YourWorker, 'args' => args)
end
```

Comment: As a follow up, is it possible to push multiple jobs of different types in bulk or is `push_bulk` designed only to allow you to push jobs of the same type with an array of arguments?

Comment: One type only per call.